# What does this mean in DB2: DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND..?

Tags: db2

I am trying to understand the meaning of this DB2 statement:

`DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND`

This appears in the IBM code example for the LOOP statement [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzloopstmt.htm), and which I've pasted below. Other than `DECLARE`, I'm not sure which of the other words are discrete keywords, and I cannot find anything helpful in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzintro.htm).

It seems like the Visual Basic statement `ON ERROR GOTO labelname`, and in context seems to be saying "return -1 if not found". But I'm not certain how or where it kicks in, or whether it refers to the SQL, the LOOP, or or what exactly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LOOP_UNTIL_SPACE (OUT COUNTER INTEGER)
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_counter INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_firstnme VARCHAR(12);
    DECLARE v_midinit CHAR(1);
    DECLARE v_lastname VARCHAR(15);
    DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT firstnme, midinit, lastname
        FROM employee;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND -- <--?
        SET counter = -1;                  -- <--?
    OPEN c1;
    fetch_loop:
    LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO v_firstnme, v_midinit, v_lastname;
        IF v_midinit = ' ' THEN
            LEAVE fetch_loop;
        END IF;
        SET v_counter = v_counter + 1;
    END LOOP fetch_loop;
    SET counter = v_counter;
    CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Comment: You can find documentation for the SQL PL (procedural language) constructs [in the same online manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcompoundstmt.htm)

Comment: Thank you, that link is very helpful. Now I see why it was so difficult to find help for this: the individual words are each too common, and the whole phrase doesn't appear in that help page as one.

Comment: Note that, as is, the sample you have got may result in an infinite loop if there are no rows in `employee` with a blank `midinit`. Normally you would have a conditional loop (e.g. `while v_flag <> 1`) and `set v_flag = 1` in the exception handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND -- <--?
        SET counter = -1;                  -- <--?
```

means that whenever an SQL statement returns SQLCODE=100 (no rows found), then execute this single-statement `set counter = -1` and then continue executing the next statement (i.e. the statement that follows the statement triggering the SQLCODE 100).

In your code example, the statement following FETCH that got sqlcode=100 will execute next.

As `counter` is an output parameter, the consequence is that `counter` will be set to -1 whenever sqlcode 100 happens. This may not be what was intended.

Comment: Thank you, that all seems like what I was thinking, but I couldn't understand the proper flow of what should happen. This put together with the [help link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcompoundstmt.htm) that @mustaccio shared in his other comment, it really helps my understanding a lot.